# libhdf5.so.103: cannot open shared object file

Tags: eclipse

I have met a problem with [hdf5 libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbYjF.png) on eclipse CDT. When running a test C++ program, I got prompt information as below:

> /home/lsl/Documents/CODE/eclipse-workspace/ReadWriteHDF5/Debug/ReadWriteHDF5:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.103: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory.

`libhdf5.so` is confirmed to exist in `/usr/local/lib/hdf5-1.10.4/lib` and `/usr/local/lib/hdf5-1.10.4/lib` is within `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Do you have any indications?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Linux is your main operating system. See what happens when you type

`sudo apt install libhdf5-dev`

since it might supplant the package you're looking for. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I come across similar issue while compiling C++ code that uses Armadillo. Since I have anaconda installed, I find the `libhdf5.so.103` file located at `~/anaconda3/lib`. After I add the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the error disappears.

Comment: This seems to work when compiling Armadillo but when building Ensmallen the issue returns.

Answer (score 0):

I came across exactly the same problem today (perhaps the only difference is that it complaint `libhdf5.so.200` was missing). What I eventually found out is that the system (Ubuntu 20.04) already shipped with `libhdf5-dev` at version 1.10.4, and this conflicted somehow with my installed version 1.12.2. My build command line is as below:

```
clang++ <...> -L/my/custom/path/to/hdf5-1.12.2/hdf5/lib <...>
```

Since the system hdf5 is in standard location, the linker finds simultaneously two versions, causing problem.

My solution is:

```
sudo apt purge libhdf5-dev
```

Hope it helps.